# Revoke azure disk SAS (shared access signature) of disk

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-disk

I am trying to revoke SAS for VM disk using Azure PowerShell but this function returns nothing:

`Get-AzDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName <resourcegroupname>`

However, in the Azure portal I see there is a SAS:

[image]

I am not sure how to remove SAS using PowerShell. I can remove it using portal.

Comment: Hi, looking at the message in the banner, you may need to cancel the export to revoke the SAS URL. Are you able to do that?

Comment: I deleted the VM but disk didn't delete because there is an active SAS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

In my Azure Portal, I activated **SAS URL** for disk attached to an VM like below:

[image]

When I tried to delete all VM related resources, all deleted except VM Disks with an **exception** like below:

[image]

The error usually occurs if **Disk State** is in **`Active SAS`**   that don't allow **Delete** operation like below:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to revoke access to Disk by clicking **`Cancel Export`** from Portal.

If you want to do the same from **PowerShell**, you can use below commands:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant <TenantID>
Revoke-AzDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName '<RG_Name>' -DiskName '<Disk_Name>'
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm that, I checked in Azure Portal where **Disk State** is changed to **`Unattached`** like below:

[image]

When I clicked on **Delete** after revoking SAS, VM disk got deleted successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: That worked wonders